# Applying a high-pass filter on constant signal

Tags: filter, signal-processing, highpass-filter

I recently implemented a Butterworth high-pass filter (2nd order). Everything seems to work fine, except that I have a question when applying such a filter to a constant signal. As there are no high-frequency components in a constant signal, I would expect the filter to yield a constant 0 signal.

In the plots below are my results. There seems to be ``ripple'' in the first couple of frames before the high-pass filtered signal (correctly) converges to 0.

Is this a logical result from applying a Butterworth high-pass filter on a constant signal, or might there be a bug in my code?

EDIT: I've created the same filter in Octave, resulting in the same output. This indicates that we're indeed looking at the step response, as Paul R. indicates.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try your question [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input to your filter is essentially a step function (since it has value 0 prior to t = 0, and a positive value for t > 0), so you see the [step response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_response) of the filter, hence the initial ringing. This is expected behaviour, and after a suitable amount of time the step response will have settled to zero.